# SQL Server (2008) Creating link tables with unique rows

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I'm having trouble getting in touch with SQL Server Managemen Studio 2008! I want to create a link-table that will link an Event to many Audiences (EventAudience).

An example of the data that could be contained:

### EventId  |  AudienceId

```
  4              1
  5              1
  4              2
```

However, I don't want this:

### EventId  |  AudienceId

```
  4              1
  4              1
```

I've been looking at relationships and constraints.. but no joy so far!

As a sneaky second part to the question, I would like to set up the Audience table such that if a row is deleted from Audience, it will clear down the EventAudience link table in a cascading manner.

As always, ANY help/advice appreciated!

Thanks
Pete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_EventAudience ON dbo.EventAudience(EventID, AudienceID);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to create a composite UNIQUE constraint on both EventId and AudienceID.

And a foreign key relationship between this table and the Audience table that has a CASCADE DELETE should take care of your second part.

Answer (score 0):

Could also make these ids the compound primary key for the table. Since uniqueness is required of primary keys.

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_EventIdAudienceId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [EventId] ASC, [AudienceId] ASC )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing in your table designer you can ctrl click both columns and set as primary key.  Thats always seemed to work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Alternate suggestion : Use triggers.

> pseudocode...
>
> Create on-update trigger on link table...
>   if record doesn't already exist create it, else exit.

Same idea for the deletion

> pseudocode again
>
> Create on-delete trigger on audience table...
>   delete the item from the audiences table
>   locate and delete references in the link table.

Sorry it's on pseudocode, I don't have SQL server close at hand to look up syntax so I didn't want to mislead.

Comment: Downvoted for offering an alternate suggestion?  Ok.  Thanks for that.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I imagine it would be because a trigger would be a poor performer compared to a unique index and harder to debug and maintain. Just because you can do it a different way doesn't make it a good idea.